# Dynamic Spacing in Titles

Tags: sectioning, titles

The following mwe shows titles embedded in two lines. The problem is, if the title includes letters like 'g','j','p','q', etc. the bottom line is very close to these particular letters. With the command `vspace` I am able to correct it, to obtain the desired result.

I am looking for a **makro in the form of** `mytitle{<title>}`that returns the desired title layout no matter what letters are used in the title.

---

### The mentioned mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

% layout (geometry, one page, margins)
\usepackage[a4paper,left=80pt,right=80pt,top=60pt,bottom=80pt,headsep=20pt,footskip=10pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

% linespacing
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

% no indent
\parindent0pt

% skip lenghts
\setlength{\smallskipamount}{4pt}
\setlength{\medskipamount}{8pt}
\setlength{\bigskipamount}{20pt}

% fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}

Titles without height corrections:

\medskip

\hrule height 0.7pt
\smallskip
\large
\textbf{Normal Title}
\smallskip
\hrule height 0.7pt
\medskip
\medskip
\normalsize


\hrule height 0.7pt
\smallskip
\large
\textbf{Irregular Title}
\hrule height 0.7pt
\medskip
\medskip
\normalsize


Title corrected with vspace:

\medskip

\hrule height 0.7pt
\smallskip
\large
\textbf{Irregular Title}
\vspace{1.5pt}
\hrule height 0.7pt
\medskip
\medskip
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

---

### The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets rid of the "skips" and uses an `\addstackgap[2pt]{}` from the `stackengine` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

% layout (geometry, one page, margins)
\usepackage[a4paper,left=80pt,right=80pt,top=60pt,bottom=80pt,headsep=20pt,footskip=10pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

% linespacing
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

% no indent
\parindent0pt

% skip lenghts
\setlength{\smallskipamount}{4pt}
\setlength{\medskipamount}{8pt}
\setlength{\bigskipamount}{20pt}

% fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

Titles without height corrections:

\medskip

\hrule height 0.7pt
\large
\addstackgap[2pt]{\textbf{Normal Title}}
\hrule height 0.7pt
\medskip
\medskip
\normalsize


\hrule height 0.7pt
\large
\addstackgap[2pt]{\textbf{Irregular Title}}
\hrule height 0.7pt
\medskip
\medskip
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

[image]